# Remove empty span tags , but keep ones with following li tag

Tags: jquery

I am using a script that simulates a milonic menu and fills my empty HTML with data. I need to remove some empty tags left after the script runs.

I am using this to remove all li tags that have an empty span tag

```
$("li span:empty").parent().remove(); // REMOVE UNUSED LI TAGS
```

But I just noticed there are some li tags that populates an additional li tag within it and although the span is empty I need to keep that li tag . Here is HTML

```
<li class="division00"> <!----- KEEP EMPTY SPAN THAT HAS LI.SINGLE TAG ------>
    <span></span>
    <li class="single">
        <ul></ul>
    </li>


<li class="division01"> <!----- REMOVE ALL LI TAGS THAT HAVE EMPTY SPAN CLASSES ------>
    <span></span> 
        <ul></ul>
    </li>

<li class="division02"> <!----- REMOVE ALL LI TAGS THAT HAVE EMPTY SPAN CLASSES ------>
    <span></span> 
        <ul></ul>
    </li>

<li class="division03"> <!----- DO NOT REMOVE ------>
    <span>TEXT HERE</span> 
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: your html is invalid... `li` cannot have `li` as a child

Comment: YOur javascript is invalid, too. `li span:empty` is a string, so it has to be surrounded by quotation marks.

Comment: not worried about emptly li tags , if empty span then remove entire li

Comment: yes, actually I somewhat read li:empty instead of span:empty. sorry, my bad. I tend to be a little fast ^^ guess your `remove unused li tags` comment is a little misleading ^^

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your html is valid try

```
$('#myul > li').not(':has(li.single)').has('> span:empty').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dHLYa/)